# Get previous form filled data in Django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I use a custom template to display my form:

```
...
<td>Username</td>
<td><input id="id_username" type="text" maxlength="30" name="username" tabindex="1"></td>
...
```

If I submit my registration form with (for example) a required field empty, django refresh the page and show me the error. The problem are the other fields (the correct ones). They're reset and the previous data filled in is cleared. If instead of using a custom way to display a field I use `{{ form.field }}` it works fine and if there's errors in the form, django fills the other correct fields.

How can I solve this?

Comment: So why can't you use `form.field`?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman because I need to use `tabindex` attribute for example. If I use `form.field` how can I customize it?

Comment: By passing it into the widgets `attrs` dictionary.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. This way it's ok, but if I want to write the plain form field in HTML is there a way to set the previous value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

forms.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length = 30)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length = 30, 
               widget = forms.PasswordInput(render_value = False))
```

views.py

```
def form_post(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        c = {}
        template = "myloginform.html"
        if form.is_valid():
           # ... do stuff
        else:
           # Add the data you want to preserve here
           c['username'] = form.username
           # ...
           return render_to_response(template, c)
```

template myloginform.html

```
...
   <input id="id_username" type="text" maxlength="30" 
    name="username" tabindex="1" value="{{ username }}" />
...
```

Edit:
To add it to the attrs dict as mentioned by Daniel above use: 
 `uname = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'1', 'class': 'myclass'}))`