# Keep option selected on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, python-2.7, django-views

So how my code works i'll give you a gist.
When there are no files in html_files, the default option is "---", but when there exists a file in html_files there are two options now,
1) "---"
2) file. But with default still as "---"

So what i want to do is, when there exists a file in html_files I want the default option change to the current file and not "---". I cant think of a way as to how to do it. Could someone help me?

```
<span title="list resources who's involved etc">About File:
      <select class="experiment_file_selector" id="about_file" name="about_file">
        <option value="None" {% if not exp.about_file %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>---</option>
        {% for file in html_files %}
          <option value="{{ file.id }}" {% if file == exp.about_file %}selected="selected"{% endif %} >{{ file.get_base_name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select></span>
```

I added a JS script as suggested below it does the work on getting the default file on the select input tag when the exp.about_file is present but for it to get displayed on the template it needs to be manually clicked.
To automate the process i tried using .click() which seems to fail somehow.

So basically how its working, of i select the first option from the select list "---" or listFile[0] and then select the second one exp.about_file or listFile[1] manually, it delivers the result some how but its not happening with the JS script.

So could someone suggest me a method to automate the mouse click event for 
listFile[0] and listFile[1], somewhat like my JS code so that it works.

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var listFile = document.getElementById('about_file');
  if (listFile.length > 1) 
  {
    listFile[1].setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
    listFile[0].click();
    listFile[1].click();
  }
});
```

Comment: Your question is unclear: what is exp.about_file?

Comment: Its the experiment filename

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964086/get-previous-form-filled-data-in-django-forms

Answer (score 0):

It will be easy if you use javascript. Just add attribute selected="selected" when your page loaded.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  var listFile = document.getElementById('about_file');
  if (listFile.length > 1) {
    listFile[1].setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
  }
});
```

Comment: The code works, it gets the file by default but what my concern is that the file actually has to be clicked and get selected and activated for it to work. I don't know why. I have to go select the option and then the work is done

Comment: You can use `.click()` to trigger a click on first option (first file) like:
`listFile[1].click();`
Remember to add it below `listFile[1].setAttribute('selected', 'selected');`

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  var listFile = document.getElementById('about_file');
  if (listFile.length > 1) 
  {
    listFile[1].setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
    listFile[0].click();
    listFile[1].click();
  }
});

Doesnt work. Could you help

Comment: I don't know how "delivers the result" code work but if it don't run when trigger the click event,  you can replace `listFile[0].click();listFile[1].click();` by these code. I don't have enough infomation but.. anyway, just make sure that your ''delivers" code run in `if (listFile.length > 1)`.